# Google Cloud Storage - Python - Create bucket - 403 Error

Tags: python, oauth

I am trying to use the python example provide here (https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gspythonlibrary?hl=es-es)
  While i am able to get listing of buckets to work, i am unable to get create bucket working. 
  When i try create bucket using uri.create_bucket i always get the error `403 Forbidden`

I am fairly sure i have done the setup properly and also did extensive search to verify things. The full error message is as follows

```
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden\r\n'
header: Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8
header: Content-Length: 111
header: Vary: Origin
header: Date: Mon, 18 Aug 2014 07:37:00 GMT
header: Server: UploadServer ("Built on Aug 12 2014 13:30:28 (1407875428)")
header: Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gcsauthme.py", line 32, in <module>
    uri.create_bucket(headers=header_values)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/boto/storage_uri.py", line 560, in create_bucket
    storage_class)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/boto/gs/connection.py", line 104, in create_bucket
    response.status, response.reason, body)
boto.exception.GSResponseError: GSResponseError: 403 Forbidden
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access denied.</Message></Error>
```

Kindly help.

Regards

Balaji

Comment: I sorted this one out. Thanks